# 'BMSerial' does not name a type

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

This is what I see every time I compile the software:

[image]

Every time I try to compile this code with the Arduino IDE, it generates this error.

This code is for the RTK1 tracked robot. and I'm trying to control it by PS3 controller.
I'm pretty new tote whole Arduino board and compiler, as well as C++. so any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <BMSerial.h>
#include <BMPS2.h>

#define DEBUG

//#define LIPO

#define SWAPMOTORS

#define LTRIG 8
#define RTRIG 8

#define RATE 40

#define IN1 4
#define IN2 2
#define IN3 9
#define IN4 7
#define EN1 6
#define EN2 5

#define LEDA 8
#define LEDB 10

#define BUTTONA 18
#define BUTTONB 19

#define BATT 15
#define ISENA 16
#define ISENB 17

#define DEADZONE 20

int currentlpwm;
int currentrpwm;
int targetlpwm;
int targetrpwm;

long currentafilter;
long currentbfilter;
#define filter_update(filter,input,rate) (filter = filter - (filter >> rate) + input) >> rate;

BMSerial sensor(13,13);
BMPS2 ps2x(11,100);

long lastalarm;
long lastalarmcheck;
int lipolow;
int lipoverylow;
int lipocritical;

boolean autonomous;

void setup() {
#ifdef DEBUG  
  Serial.begin(625000);
#endif

  digitalWrite(LEDB,HIGH);

  lipolow = false;
  lipoverylow = false;
  lipocritical = false;

  lastalarm = millis();
  lastalarmcheck = millis();

  autonomous = false;

  sensor.begin(38400);

  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(IN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(EN1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(EN2,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(LEDA,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDB,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTONA,INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTONB,INPUT);

  digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3,LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);

  tone(3,750,100);
  delay(100);
  tone(3,1000,100);
  delay(100);
  tone(3,1250,100);
  delay(100);
}

boolean CheckLipo()
{
  long time = millis() - lastalarm;
  if(lipocritical>=10){
    //Lipo protection
    tone(3,500,250);
    delay(250);
    tone(3,800,250);
    delay(250);
    return true;
  }
  else if(lipoverylow>=10){
    //Lipo protection
    if(time>1000){
      lastalarm=millis();
      tone(3,500,100);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
  else if(lipolow>=10){
    //Lipo protection
    if(time>3000){
      lastalarm=millis();
      tone(3,500,100);
      delay(100);
    }
  }

  if((millis()-lastalarmcheck)>100){
    lastalarmcheck=millis();

    int voltage = (long)analogRead(BATT)*1500/1024;
    if(voltage<700){
      lipolow++;
      if(lipolow>10)
        lipolow=10;
    }
    else
      lipolow=0;
    if(voltage<650){
      lipoverylow++;
      if(lipoverylow>10)
        lipoverylow=10;
    }
    else
      lipoverylow=0;
    if(voltage<620)         //Orion will auto cutoff servo use at this level but there is still approx 100ma draw from all electronics
      lipocritical++;       //once triggered always triggered
    else
        lipocritical=0;
  }

  return false;
}

void loop() {
#ifdef LIPO
  if(CheckLipo()){
    digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);
    return; //Battery too low to do anything.
  }
#endif

  if(ps2x.isUpdated()){
    if(ps2x.buttonPressed(PSB_RED)){
      if(autonomous)
        autonomous=false;
      else
        autonomous=true;
    }

    int RY,LY;

    if(autonomous){
      sensor.listen();
      sensor.println("#AB");
      unsigned char rstate = sensor.readhex(10000);
      unsigned char lstate = sensor.readhex(10000);
    }
    else{
      delay(20);
      RY = ps2x.analog(PSS_RY);
      LY = ps2x.analog(PSS_LY);

      if(RY>-DEADZONE && RY<DEADZONE)
        RY=0;
      if(RY<-127)
        RY=-127;
      if(LY>-DEADZONE && LY<DEADZONE)
        LY=0;
      if(LY<-127)
        LY=-127;
    }

    setlpwm(LY);
    setrpwm(RY);
  }  
}

void setrpwm(int pwm)
{
  targetrpwm = pwm;
  if(currentrpwm<targetrpwm){
    currentrpwm+=RATE;
    if(currentrpwm>targetrpwm)
      currentrpwm=targetrpwm;
  }
  if(currentrpwm>targetrpwm){
    currentrpwm-=RATE;
    if(currentrpwm<targetrpwm)
      currentrpwm=targetrpwm;
  }

#ifdef SWAPMOTORS
  SetPWM2(currentrpwm);
#else
  SetPWM1(currentrpwm);
#endif

}

void setlpwm(int pwm)
{
  targetlpwm = pwm;
  if(currentlpwm<targetlpwm){
    currentlpwm+=RATE;
    if(currentlpwm>targetlpwm)
      currentlpwm=targetlpwm;
  }
  if(currentlpwm>targetlpwm){
    currentlpwm-=RATE;
    if(currentlpwm<targetlpwm)
      currentlpwm=targetlpwm;
  }

#ifdef SWAPMOTORS
  SetPWM1(currentlpwm);
#else
  SetPWM2(currentlpwm);
#endif

}

void SetPWM1(int pwm)
{
  if(pwm>0){
    digitalWrite(IN1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);
  }
  if(pwm<0){
    digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2,HIGH);
  }
  if(pwm==0){
    digitalWrite(IN1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN2,LOW);
  }
  analogWrite(EN1,abs(pwm*2));
}

void SetPWM2(int pwm)
{
  if(pwm>0){
    digitalWrite(IN3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);
  }
  if(pwm<0){
    digitalWrite(IN3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN4,HIGH);
  }
  if(pwm==0){
    digitalWrite(IN3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(IN4,LOW);
  }
  analogWrite(EN2,abs(pwm*2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple things first: Unless it has changed recently (or is different on Windows than on OSX), you need to have your libraries in Arduino -> Libraries folder (or within your sketch folder but that is generally not a good practice with 3rd party libs).

I can't tell for sure from your screenshot but it doesn't look like you have them there. If that is the case, not sure why the #include statement doesn't throw and error.